# how to itearte list objects using JSTL in jsp and check for the conditions based in the list object value

Tags: java, list, jsp, jstl

I have a map object which consists of key as a string and value as list of strings, all i need to do is iterate over this list with JSTL

for example;

List consists of String objects as follows, : ["192.168.0.0","admin","true"]

each list object value should be placed under a header in a table like

```
Messaging      Role     status
192.168.0.0   admin     true
```

I am able to get this output. however, my requirement is to test for a condition in a list object, if the status is true, then i need to print as STARTED , if false-> STOPPED.

My code:

```
model.put("notifierList", list);
```

inside JSP:

```
 <tr>   
<c:forEach items="${notifierList}" var="entry">

<td>
${entry}
</td>
 </c:forEach>
        </tr>
```

how can i itearted the list object in JSTl and check for the above condition. kindly provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using ternary operator `?:`.

```
 <c:if test="${entry=='true' || entry == 'false'}">
 ${entry eq 'true' ? 'STARTED' : 'STOPPED'}
 </c:if>
```

Comment: Remove the `status` property since it is a list of `String`.

Comment: entry.status will not work.. any other suggestions pls

Comment: @Jalal, whtat is the type of `entry`? Is it a Class object or String array?

Comment: here entry is a string object not a class

Answer (score 0):

one way is you can split your string and check status index .
if it is true then STARTED otherwise  STOPPED.